# database data never show in html

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, categories

I tried to collect category data from database and show in the category dropdown list in html. However, it won't work. I have no idea which part is going wrong. The output return null, it never collect any data from database category table.

This is my html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}



</style>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ionic.min.css" />
    <title>Create an Account</title>
</head>
<body onload="selectCategory()">
<div class="bar bar-header">
    <a href="index.html" class="button button-clear button-royal">Back</a>
    <h1 class="title">Add an Item</h1>

</div>
<div class="padding" style="margin-top:75px;">
    <label class="item-input">
        <span class="input-label">Item Name</span>
        <input type="text" placeholder="" id="itemName">
    </label>
    <label class="item-input">
        <span class="input-label">Category</span>
        <select id="select_category">
            <option value="0">- Select -</option>
        </select>

    </label>
    <label class="item-input">
        <button class="button button-block button-positive" id="signup">Add item</button>
    </label>


</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jq.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/addProduct.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

addProduct.js

```
    function selectCategory() {
        $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://selectCategory.php?callback=?',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: "",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success:function(response){

                        var len = response.length;

                        $("#select_category").empty();
                        for( var i = 0; i<len; i++){
                            var id = response[i]['id'];
                            var name = response[i]['name'];

                            $("#select_category").append("<option value='"+id+"'>"+name+"</option>");

                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

selectCategory.php

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

$host = 'localhost';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$database = 'database';

$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM category");

$users_arr = array();

while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $users_arr[] = array("id" => $row['id'], "name" => $row['name']);
}

// encoding array to json format
echo json_encode($users_arr);
?>
```

Comment: In addProduct.js, Remove http:// from http://selectCategory.php?callback=?

Comment: Actually this is a phonegap project, the php file is store at online server which is different location with the html file

Comment: OK, add the domain name or IP address before selectCategory.php

Comment: yah,I did and remove the callback also but it return null

Comment: If you go to selectCategory.php directly does it output text?

Comment: I directly go that php file,output is null.However, there are data inside my database category table and for my category table there are id,name,description ,three row

Comment: Please check my answer below

Comment: yes,selectCategory.php return me the correct data now but it still never display in html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `mysql_connect` and `mysql_select_db` which are deprecated functions. Use PDO to access your database instead:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

$host = 'localhost';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$database = 'database';

$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM category");

$users_arr = array();

while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $users_arr[] = array("id" => $row['id'], "name" => $row['name']);
}

// encoding array to json format
echo json_encode($users_arr);
?>
```

Comment: With this code, the selectCategory.php has returned me the correct data already, but it still won't display in html file

Comment: Two things: in your <body> tag you have body twice. In your $.ajax, change type to 'get'

Comment: I have removed the body already. I change the type to get also but it wont display as well

Comment: I think is not get or post issue

Comment: Put console.log(response) in the success function, does it display anything in the developers console?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: selectCategory is not defined
    at onload (addProduct.html:22) . This is the error I received in developers console but I have defined selectCategory in addProduct.js

Comment: I found the answer, need to move the selectCategory function out of $(document).ready(function(), will accept your answer later

Answer (score 0):

In the selectCategory.php file you have the following part:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'http://selectCategory.php?callback=?',
```

You have HTTP in your request, which is supposed to be a call for a different domain, which in your case is not, also the callback argument actually isnt doing anything, try changing it like so:

```
$.ajax({
   url: '/selectCategory.php',
```

Comment: Actually this is a phonegap project, the php file is store at online server which is different location with the html file

Comment: Then you have to put the location of your online server on the ajax call

Comment: yes, i did and i removed the callback argument also,but when I directly go the location of selectCategory.php, it return me null

Comment: Use PDO or mysqli object oriented style, because you are referencing a $con variable which doesnt exist

Comment: yah,I did, I use PDO now and selectCategory.php return me correct data now. However,it still won't display in html file.